# How can I pass parameter to event listener in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have component like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const WindowFocusHandler = ({store}) => {
  // here store object is valid and work
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('focus', () => {
      console.log('Tab is in focus... but no store object here', store);
    
    });
  });

  return <></>;
};

export default WindowFocusHandler;
```

And I am trying to pass `store` object inside listener function but failed what ever I try.

Comment: Did you pass Store to WindowFocusHandler?

Comment: `store` is for sure in the scope, and is accessible from inside the effect. The problem must be in the component call. This is not a problem of scope, the object is already coming nullified

Comment: Component is added in app root <WindowFocusHandler store={store}/>. If I try `(store) => ...` I get event of window not my store that I passed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const WindowFocusHandler = ({ store }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fn = () => {
      console.log('Tab is in focus...', store);
    };

    window.addEventListener('focus', fn);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('focus', fn);
  }, [store]);

  return <></>;
};

export default WindowFocusHandler;
```

Comment: useEffect depends on `fn` and does not depend on `store`. You can create `fn` inside useEffect. Or wrap fn with useCallback with dep [store] and change dep for useEffect [fn].

Comment: Yeah, good call. I edited my answer. Thanks for looking out!